# T type default value

Tags: c#, types, extension-methods

I had several Extension Methods like `ParseInt`, `ParseLong`, `ParseByte`. now I'm trying to make a single extension method for all of them. the problem is that to make the `Default` parameter optional I have to give it a value like `T Default = 0`, but it generates the error:

> A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'T'

If I use it like `T Default = (T)0` then I get another error:

> Cannot convert type 'int' to 'T'

This is my extension method:

```
public static T Parse<T>(this string x, T Default = 0)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            if(type == typeof(int))
            { if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) int.TryParse(x , out Defualt); return Default;  }
        }
```

Comment: not sure to see the point between using `Parse<int>` or `ParseInt` in both case you have to be "explicit" about the return type

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Some off-topic tips. **1.** Instead of `typeof(T) == typeof(int)`, you could just do `Default is int`. **2.** Parameter names usually start with a small letter. Now `default` is already a C# keyword, but you can still call your parameter that by escaping it: `@default`. Of course it might be nicer to just rename the parameter to `defaultValue` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use `default(T)` instead:

```
public static T Parse<T>(this string x, T defaultValue = default(T))
```

However, I would strongly question the design here - you're not really writing a generic method, but a method which accepts one of a specific set of types and treats each one differently. There are times where this is enforced on you, but I'd typically have a `Dictionary<T, SomeDelegate>` to try to handle it more cleanly.

In addition, you're still going to have problems calling `int.TryParse` - you can't use the parameter to `Parse<T>` as an argument - you'd need something like:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
{
    // You need to consider what you want to happen if
    // int.TryParse returns false - do you want to return 0,
    // or defaultValue?
    int ret;
    if (int.TryParse(x, out ret))
    {
        // Annoying but required due to which conversions are available
        return (T)(object) ret;
    }
}
return defaultValue;
```

Comment: I didn't get it, what is the use of Dictionary in here

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: You'd have a delegate for each implementation, which you could look up by type. It avoids having one very long method.

Answer (score 1):

Like another answer mentioned already, you can get a generic type's default value as a compile-time constant by using the `default` keyword: `default(T)` in your case.

- If `T` is a class or interface type, `default(T)` is the null reference.
- If `T` is a struct, then `default(T)` is the value where all the bits are zero. This is `0` for numeric types, `false` for `bool`, and a combination of both of these rules for custom `struct`s.

---

But: **Don't do this. Don't create this generic method** when it's only going to work for a few handpicked types. As a general rule, generic methods are intended to work for *all* types. (You can constrain the valid types with generic parameter constraints `where T : …` but that doesn't change the basic idea.)

In your case, the generic method is only going to work for a few types like `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, etc. You even have to check for these types in your generic method already so that you can defer to the right method (`int.TryParse`, `double.TryParse`, etc.). That's a big sign that your method shouldn't be generic at all.

**Stay with your previous extension methods `ParseInt`, `ParseSingle`, `ParseDouble`, etc.** It was the better design.